# In memory cache with multiple keys

Tags: c#, caching

I need to build a cache of one of my custom class objects(security as in finance). The object of the class can be identified in multiple ways since it has multiple identifiers like PKey, Name, Long Name, or any other type of name in different language.

So the cache should be searchable on the basis of any of the identifiers i.e. multiple keys.

How can I create such a cache?

I am using C# 4.5 but I think this is a generic problem, so solutions in any way can help

One of the solutions which I think is fast and efficient is to keep different caches for different identifiers. For e.g. < Name,Pkey>,  < Long Name,Pkey>, < identifier,Pkey> and a single cache with objects of type < Pkey,Object>

Are there newer and better ways to do this?

> Edit: When I am accessing the cache all the keys are not known, so I
>   can not make a composite key

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will be useful:

```
public class Test12 {
    static Map<CacheKey, SecureObject> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<CacheKey, SecureObject>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SecureObject secureObject = new SecureObject(new CacheKey("pkey1", "name1", 1L));
        cache.put(secureObject.getKey(), secureObject);
        secureObject = new SecureObject(new CacheKey("pkey1", "name2", 2L));
        if (cache.containsKey(secureObject.getKey())) {
            System.out.println("Already in cache.");
        }
    }
}

class CacheKey {
    String pkey;
    String name;
    Long longName;

    CacheKey(String pkey, String name, Long longName) {
        this.pkey = pkey;
        this.name = name;
        this.longName = longName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        CacheKey cacheKey = (CacheKey) o;

        if (pkey != null && pkey.equals(cacheKey.pkey)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if (name != null && name.equals(cacheKey.name)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                if (longName != null && longName.equals(cacheKey.longName)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 0;

        if (pkey != null) {
            result = pkey.hashCode();
        } else if (name != null) {
            result = name.hashCode();
        } else if (longName != null) {
            result = longName.hashCode();
        }

        return result;
    }
}

class SecureObject {
    CacheKey key;

    SecureObject(CacheKey key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public CacheKey getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(CacheKey key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

Prints:

> Already in cache.

This is not complete solution. This is direction only.

Comment: You got me wrong, all keys are not known everytime you access the cache . I need to access the cache using only one key

Comment: Isn't this Java? OP said he's using C#, and this question is also tagged as such.

Comment: Tobias, if I don't mistake, this question was tagged with 'java' too. And I saw it in java-feed.

Comment: This approach allow searching on only 1 key too, I think. Try with null for 2 others keys.

Comment: No problem with Java too. The only thing which matters right now will be the correct approach.